# Checking THRE to send characters via serial

Tags: c, linux, uart

I'm trying to send a string to a serial port using:

```
#define UART    0x03f8
...
#define UART_LSR_THRE 0x20
...
void UART_send(unsigned char *data){
     int i = 0, k = strlen(data);
     printk("UART_send invoked, data is %s and k is %d\n", data, k);
     while(i < k){
       while( !(inb(UART + UART_LSR_THRE)) ){
             printk("called\n");
             schedule();
       }
       if(i < k){
             outb(data[i++], (UART + UART_TX));
       }
    }
}
```

When trying write ABCDEF, for example, sometimes it skips letters or prints them more than once. My guess is that I'm not verifying the status of the THRE correctly, seeing as it's not only the wrong result, the while() being there or not doesn't seem to be doing anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Usually you need to check a Transmit Buffer Empty *status bit* (in a status register) to determine when to write to the TXD register.  Your code is checking an entire *register*.  If `THRE` is supposed to be "Transmit Holding Register Empty", then is this value supposed to be a register offset or a bit mask?  HINT: what is `LSR` (as in `UART_LSR_THRE`)?

Comment: In this case UART_LSR_THRE is an offset. I'm having trouble understanding how this is all organized. So UART has several 8 bit register, and I'm trying to check one bit in one of the registers, but I'm not getting how to get there. In this code, if I use UART_LSR_THRE instead of (UART + UART_LSR_THRE) all the letters are sent, albeit slowly. It works, but I don't understand why.

Comment: *"UART_LSR_THRE is an offset"* - You failed to grasp the hint and I think you're wrong.  I'm going to assume that you are using an 8250 UART, even though you have not specified anything, but you do have `#define UART 0x03f8` which is a distinctive PC I/O address.  The spec sheet for the 8250 has a **Line Status Register** aka `LSR`.  In this LSR register **bit 5** is defined as `THRE`, which would correspond to a **bit mask** of `0x20`.    Reading location `UART + UART_LSR_THRE` or `UART_LSR_THRE` is probably garbage.  You need to read `UART + UART_LSR` and then apply the mask `UART_LSR_THRE`.